# Rest API in Heroku returns 404, but no problems in local tomcat 200 with proper response contents

Tags: javascript, java, heroku, tomcat, jersey

I have built a Java Backend with Jersey services,
Which I can fetch from with a front end javascript.

When I run it locally on tomcat I have no issues;

`POST http://localhost:8080/restservices/authentication/`
with the response being a working JWToken.

Whereas wheN I try to hos this on heroku, I keep getting a 404 response saying it cannot find it.

`POST https://archive-trawler.herokuapp.com/restservices/authentication/`

```html
Type Status Report
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Message The requested resource [/restservices/authentication/] is not available
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/9.0.52
```

I noticed this in the build logs today:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack

-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app

 !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.

            Detected buildpacks: Java,Node.js

            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
```

So I am guessing the buildpacks are related. But this surpasses my knowledge by far.

Comment: Please, no screenshots of code or error messages.

Comment: oh sorry yeah for searchability I guess? makes sense! SO sorry will Write it out